# How to stop Refresh/Reload of page in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I think page load is bigest issue of asp.net(webform)

I reserach alot about but i not get any solution

I use update panel but update panel not work

So please expect update panel give any other solution

e.g I have button i click onbutton after that full page goes refersh but i dnt want this

Is this possible when i click on button just show some progress bar for refershing page

Please give some suitable example

Because Page load so irrating me

Thanks :)

**Update**

```
  <asp:button ID="btn" runat="server" onclick="btn_click" />
```

Now here i want to show datalist data without loading page

```
    <asp:datalist ID="dlist" runat="server" >
    <item template>
          <asp:label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comments") %>'/>
    </item template>
    </asp:datalist>
```

Comment: Posting the code that you are having issues with will help you get good answers.  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Show us your code. Then only someone from us can help you. We can't imagine what you've done so far. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of JQuery or Javascript if you want  to use Update panel.

Here is the code that will do work for you.

**default.aspx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:button ID="btn" runat="server" OnClick="btn_click" />
<asp:datalist ID="dlist" runat="server" >
<itemtemplate>
      <asp:label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Comments") %>'/>
</itemtemplate>
</asp:datalist>

</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Then at back end I've given datatable to the datalist by following way.

**default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   //*Here You'll have to put your Own Logic. I've binded datalist just for example.*
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Comments");
    dt.Rows.Add("abc");
    dlist.DataSource = dt;
    dlist.DataBind();
}
```

> Update panel always works. and there is no reason to hate this
>   control. Yeah, If you want to perform operations from your front end
>   only then Jquery is best choice.